# Trying to run a simple logistic regression without luck

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a logistic regression on a small data set, but after going at it for three weeks I am about to give up. I have been getting a range of error messages and I am now even having doubts whether my R engine is working as it should. `DPUT` of my data looks like this:

```
structure(list(SEASON = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), OO_OBS = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), HW_OBS = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), F_OO = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), F_HW = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), INIT_OO = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    INIT_HW = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    INIT_BOTH = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "NA"), class = "factor"), 
    as.is = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE)), .Names = c("SEASON", "OO_OBS", "HW_OBS", "F_OO", 
"F_HW", "INIT_OO", "INIT_HW", "INIT_BOTH", "as.is"), row.names = c(NA, 
-119L), class = "data.frame")
```

These variables are all factors with two levels, except `SEASON`, that has three levels.

I want to run a logistic regression where "F_HW" is the response variable and "SEASON" and "F_OO" are dependent variables. This is the script I have been trying to run, which should be really simple, but it doesn't work (my data object is called `feed.df`):

```
feed.df$SEASON <- as.factor(feed.df$SEASON)
feed.df$F_OO <- as.factor(feed.df$F_OO)
feed.df$FEED_HW <- as.factor(feed.df$FEED_HW)

attach(feed.df)
ml <- glm(F_HW ~ SEASON + F_OO, family=binomial)

lm.out = glm(F_HW ~ SEASON + F_OO, family=binomial)
summary (lm.out)
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. I did `ml <- glm(F_HW ~ SEASON + F_OO, data=feed.df, family=binomial); lm.out = glm(F_HW ~ SEASON + F_OO, data=feed.df, family=binomial)` instead of `attach(...)`. _"it doesn't work "_ is generally not very helpful in describing a problem.

Comment: Don't use attach() - you will shot you in your foot. http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf section 8.1.36  Better use `data=` in many functions. There are also `with()` and `transform()`

Comment: Forget `attach()`. It should never have existed in the first place.